# FindItemWithText listview clickevent or itemchecked event

Tags: vb.net, listview, search

I tried the both events.. but the result is always the same. I have two listview(lvMessage and lvContact)

> lvMessage (1st lisview - Items are from sim card) index 0 | Null
>
> index 1 | Cell Number - (lets say i have {"1234", "2468"})
>
> index 2 | Date and Time
>
> index 3 | Message
>
> lvContact(2nd listview)
>
> index 0 | ID
>
> index 1 | Name - (lets say i have {"Chris", "Mark", "Cedric"})
>
> index 2 | Number - (lets say i have {"1234", "2468"})

here is my code:

```
Dim ChkContact As New ListViewItem

            Dim TheText As ListViewItem = Me.lvMessage.Items(0)

            ChkContact = lvContact2.FindItemWithText(TheText.SubItems(1).Text.ToString)
            If ChkContact IsNot Nothing Then
                txtContact.Text = ChkContact.SubItems(1).Text
                lvMessage.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text = ChkContact.SubItems(1).Text

            Else
                txtContact.Text = "no match found"
                lvMessage.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text = "Not in the list"
            End If
```

the result in index(0) in my 1st listview(lvMessage) is "Chris"

even I click or checked other rows the result is always "Chris"

please help.. I know the code is working in FindItemWith text but the result I want is always the same...

thanks

Comment: Anyone? please help... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess..

```
Dim TheText As ListViewItem = Me.lvMessage.Items(0)
```

This code will always select the first Item on your lvMessage 
and this will always be "Chris"

```
TheText.SubItems(1).Text.ToString
```

Try this..

```
 Dim TheText As ListViewItem = Me.lvMessage.SelectedItems(0)
```

it will get the first selected item on your lvMessage.

Comment: hi Diaton... thanks.. but i got this error when I changed it..invalidArgument = Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'
parameter name: index.... I used lvMessage_SelectedIndexChanged... when I click the first row, the name change to "chris" but when click the 2nd row. That's the error...

Comment: can you add the codes for the creation of the lvMessage and lvContacts?